# Login to a website using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

Im a fresher to Excel Macros (VBA) and looking for a way to automate IE to login to a website and proceed to a certain page.
website URL : https://www.mast-technicalservices.com/ecp/index2.jsp and need to fill the login details and click continue.

```
Sub WebsiteLogIn()

Dim nURL As String
Dim UNElementID As String
Dim UserName As String
Dim PWElementID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SIElementID As String


Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set nURL = "https://www.mast-technicalservices.com/ecp/index2.jsp"
Set UNElementID = "ecp_param_userId"
Set UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
Set PWElementID = "ecp_param_password"
Set Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value
Set SIElementID = "imageField2"

Dim IE              As Object
Dim IEPage          As Object
Dim IEPageElement   As Object


    'Create a new Internet Explorer instance, make it visible and maximize its window and navigate to url.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

    IE.navigate URL

    Set IEPage = IE.document

    'setthe UserName text box using the element ID.
    Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById(UNElementID)

    'set the Password text box using the element ID.
    Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById(PWElementID)


    'set the Continue button using the element ID.
    Set IEPageElement = IEPage.getElementById(SIElementID)


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using a `WebBrowser` ActiveX control in a User Form, or an `XMLHttpRequest` object in a User Module?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so people can assist you with errors/issues. You are welcome to search for similar questions to find the answer you are looking for.  To try to help you along, I suggest you look at Powershell and UI-Automation (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=uiautomation). I have used that combination to auto launch Internet Explorer and login a saved username and password along with additional steps. If you want to move forward with powershelgl, update your question and I'll try to assist.

Comment: i haven't started anything to on this, basically im looking for help to get this done.

Comment: I have tried this to navigate to URL but has some issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
Sub login()

    Const Url$ = "https://www.mast-technicalservices.com/ecp/index2.jsp"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
    Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("ecp_param_userId")(0)
        Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("ecp_param_password")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password
        .document.forms(0).submit

    End With

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

The other sub: `ieBusy` will ensure the webpage is fully loaded prior to you attempting to manipulate it.

Comment: I tried the code but i get a run-time error "Automation error and Unspecified error "
Debug points to line
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Comment: Any more error details? Did it point to a specific line? I tried the code myself and it worked (I admit however, it was prior to my most current update).

Comment: i have tried to use READYSTATE option few times earlier and those failed as well.
Is there any other controls or references that i have to enable to use this code?

Comment: ooops that's because you are using latebinding. Replace READYSTATE_COMPLETE with the number `4`.

Comment: Still the same. debug points to this line
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4

Comment: @SEEDSSupport once again, case of the "Late Binding". I apologize! Replace `(ie As InternetExplorer)` with `(ie As Object)`

Comment: Also, make sure in IE settings that you have Enable Protected Mode checked under Security.

Comment: worked like a charm, now we have o go to the next step. I need to click one of the buttons in the next page and then select from a menu on the following page. problem is i cannot give out the login information.how can we do it.is it OK if i give you the source of the site.

Comment: @SEEDSSupport I am not sure what to say. Did you completely delete your code and replace with mine? Do you have any publicly declared variables?

Comment: @Davis , I have used your code to login to the page.now the next challenge is to select a button from the next page which will go to another page where i need to select on item from a menu.is there a secure way to share a login detail to you.

Comment: @SEEDSSupport Although I consider myself 100% trustworthy, I would hate for leakage somehow. Could you possibly take a screen shot of the html code in question? Or type it out in a question?

Comment: Here is the code for the element that i told about.
<input name="reportIIS" value="Select" class="button" onclick="javascript: onSelect('/cooapp/servlet/CooMainServlet?command=SelectProgram&amp;programType=IIS')" type="button">