# Login to website VBA yields error when changing Name

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I found here a code that actually input login data and login to website. It works on that website (so references are turned on correctly) - [Login to a website using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919491/login-to-a-website-using-vba) . I am trying to use that in a company but I get an error when I adjust the names.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Error:**
Run-time error 438
Object doesnt support this property or method.

It appears at line "oLogin.Value = UserName"

```
Sub login()

Const Url$ = "site.company.org"

Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie

    .navigate Url
    ieBusy ie
    .Visible = True

    Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
    Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("login")(0)
    Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("heslo")(0)

    oLogin.Value = UserName
    oPassword.Value = Password
    .document.forms(0).submit

End With
End Sub



Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Here is HTML for my website

```html
<form name="login" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./index.php?page=main/login.php">
<input type="hidden" name="chyba" value=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="odeslano" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="redir_url" value="http://zinfo.kamax.org/">

<table align="left" class="NORMAL left">
<tbody><tr>
 <td align="right">*Login:</td>
 <td align="left"><input class="polozka_formulare_req" type="text" name="login" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" autofocus="autofocus"></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
 <td align="right">*Password:</td>
 <td align="left"><input class="polozka_formulare_req" type="password" name="heslo" size="12" maxlength="12" value=""></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td align="right"></td>
 <td align="center">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="TLAC">
  <!--<button class="TLAC" type="button" onClick="window.open('//website.company.org/','_self');return false;">Back</button>-->
 </td>
</tr> 
</tbody></table>

<div class="login_warn">
        Important Note to all Users:
        <br><br>
        All Documents in this system are for company internal use only. 
        Forwarding of any document or even parts of it to external parties without prior approval by QM or RD is strictly prohibited.
        </div>
    
</form>
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: oLogin.Value = UserName

Comment: Is this form in an iFrame? I can't tell from the code snippet provided. For example, if you are looking at your question on this page, it's in an iFrame - you can tell because of the tagname iFrame when looking at F12 dev tools.

Comment: Well, I should reword that - your actual question itself on this page isn't in an iframe - but your HTML code snippet is. You will see it under `<iframe name="f418e912-6133-b1f7-7113-98bdf2d08ad6" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts" class="snippet-box-edit" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could target the input boxes. As noted you would need to handle frames/iframes first if they are present.

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[name=login]").Value ="n"
ie.document.querySelector("input[type=password]").Value ="x"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use an `oLogin` generic object, try referencing the webform directly like this:

`ie.Document.ALL.login.Value = UserName`

`ie.Document.ALL.heslo.Value = Password`

Comment: I am getting the same error, however QHarr solved the issue

Comment: Glad you got it solved. I’ll +1 his answer to send it upward